# @font-face not working in IE when not on server

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iis, font-face

I have implemented @font-face for a number of fonts on a website. This is an asp website hosted on IIS7. Currently I am testing with FF23, Chrome, IE8/9/10. I am having some difficulties with the fonts in IE. When I am not accessing the webpage from my server the fonts will render properly on FF and Chrome, however on all the IE browsers they will not. When I am accessing the website on the server(2008 r2) I am using the same URL(fully qualified domain name). When I am accessing not on the server I am using the same fully qualified domain name. Both the fonts and the website are hosted on the same machine(same domain). There are no errors thrown by @font-face in FF or Chrome, not sure how to check in ie.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sf_movie_posterregular';
    src: url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.svg#sf_movie_posterregular') format('svg'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: To see error messages in IE, hit F12 and go to the **Console** tab.

Answer (score 2):

Add woff as a mine type to IIS. (.woff, application/font-woff)

Go to IIS Manager, and select your website, and choose MIME Types from the right.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for the suggestion. Two things; does IE use EOT format, and it worked using fully qualified domain from the server why would it work here if I didnt have proper mime types set?

Comment: When it's coming from the server, it probably has the correct MIME type. IE9 and later use WOFF, earlier IE versions use EOT.

Comment: hm, this still didnt seem to work. I tried .woff application/font-woff and .woff application/x-font-woff

Comment: I get prompted to download the fonts on IE after changing that browser property but the fonts are not used

Comment: Using fiddler I can see it getting all the fonts, but its only downloading the svg font for some reason.

Comment: I also had to add .svg (image/svg+xml)

Answer (score 0):

After adding 'local' to the fonts, it worked accross all browsers.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sf_movie_posterregular';
    src: url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot');
    src: local( 'sf_movie_posterregular'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.svg#sf_movie_posterregular') format('svg'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/customtitle-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```